# slideDown immediate li and slide up other li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to slideUp all  `li` element and slideDown `li` elements under current `ul` element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").slideUp();
});

$(".nav").hover(function(e){
    $(this).children("li").slideDown();
    $("li").slideUp();
    e.stopPropogation();
});
```

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/44/) is the fiddle

Problem is it is sliding up everything in the end
What is the mistake i have done?

Comment: A text node is not a valid child of a `ul`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the `LI`s of all other navs *excluding the current one*, so use `not`:

e.g.

```
 $(".nav").hover(function (e) {
     $(this).children("li").slideDown();
     $(".nav").not(this).find("li").slideUp();
     e.stopPropogation();
 });
```

**JSDFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kcGZJ/46/

As you are having issues of overlapping actions, the usual "fix" is to stop prior animations so they at least do not chain and run to completion:

```
 $(".nav").hover(function (e) {
     $(this).children("li").stop(true,true).slideDown();
     $(".nav").not(this).find("li").stop(true,true).slideUp();
     e.stopPropogation();
 });
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kcGZJ/55/

Comment: Thanks ! i have a small problem here http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/49/ 
When i navigate over 2, it expands 3's li as it slides up!!

Comment: You will find similar problems with any code that allows you to hover over items being added underneath it.

Comment: oh any suggestion for it?

Comment: @vignesh: Try my new version using `stop`. This will reduce chaining of animations at least.

Comment: Hey thanks but i am facing issues with second level menu !! http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/56/

Comment: pls check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773166/second-level-menu-item-using-ul-li-not-working

Answer (score 3):

You can separate your `hover()` event hook in to two calls, one for `mouseenter` and another for `mouseleave`. On `mouseenter` you want to `slideDown()` the `li` in the current `ul`. In the `mouseleave`, you want to make them all `slideUp()`. Try this:

```
$(".nav").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("li").slideDown();
}, function() {
    $("li").slideUp();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/47/)

Comment: thanks Rory!!
Rory if 2nd ul is having only 2 elements, then when i hover over 1, then over 2, it automatically hovers over 3 as 1 elements slides up
any suggestion for it?

Comment: There's not really much you can do about that - it's a flaw of the design as the hit area which raised the event is moving.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code `$(this).children("li").slideDown();` makes all li to slide down. And, `$("li").slideUp();` will make all li slideup!!

Please do

```
$(".nav").hover(function (e) {
 $(".nav").not(this).find("li").slideUp();
 $(this).children("li").slideDown();
 e.stopPropogation();
```

});

refer [jQuery not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Please check before posting that there is not a [near] identical answer already. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a class to fix this issue

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("li").slideUp();
        });

         $(".nav").hover(function(e){
            $("li").removeClass();
            $(this).children("li").addClass("current").slideDown();
            $("li:not(.current)").slideUp();
            e.stopPropogation();
         });
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/kcGZJ/89/)