# Second level menu item using ul li not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a collapsible `ul li`.

It works fine for the first level, but it is not expanding the `ul` elements inside the `li` (second level menu).

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").slideUp();
});

var hovering = 0;
var element;
$("ul,li").mouseenter(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { clearHover(); }, 1000);
    if (hovering == 0)
    {
        hovering = 1;
        $("#testdiv").css({ "background-color": "red" });
        $(this).find("> li").delay(500).slideDown("medium");
        $(".nav").not(this).find("li").delay(500).slideUp();
    }
});

function clearHover() {
    hovering = 0;
    $("#testdiv").css({ "background-color": "green" });
};
```

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/56/)

I tried to simplify the code using `show, hide`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("li").slideUp();
     // setTimeout(function(){ $("ul li").slideDown(); },1000);
 });


 $("ul").hover(function (e) {
     $(this).children().stop(true,true).show();
     $(".nav").not(this).find("li").stop(true,true).hide();
});

 $("li").hover(function (e) {
     if($(this).children().length>0){
     $(this).children().show();
         $(this).children("ul").css({"z-index":"100"});
     }
     //console.log($(this).children().length+ " " + Math.random);

});
```

Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/75/)

Comment: There are some basic UI design issues you need to resolve first. Where do you want the grandchild items to be placed? Beside or under their parent? There is an inherent z-order problem with nested lists.

Comment: under their parent, after hovering on them

Comment: Is this simply intended to be a menu system? If so you are better off using one of many (many) menu plugins available.

Comment: No this is already existing, and the structure is like this(with ul inside li) 
so need to accomodate that change

Comment: Most menu plugins work with nested UL/LIs, so that is not a problem.

Comment: even usage of show hide is fine, if slideup down causes problems

Comment: The horrible part is creating styling for recursive items :) Are you able to adjust your HTML at all as it is invalid to have text as an immediate child of a UL. You need to introduce "header" LIs there and style them differently.

Comment: hey check out my second fiddle link in the end of the question

Comment: Already using an improved version of that. Please respond to previous question (your HTML is invalid, are you allowed to change it?)

Comment: yeah you can remove that text

Comment: Okay: I have no more time for this, but here is a starting point for you and others: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kcGZJ/86/ I used `.header` LI elements to contain the text for the parent LI. I can't get the z-index to work, so they continue to move under the siblings.

Answer (score 0):

If you seek to expand the whole 3rd level once on mouse over on the level 2, you need to add a parent selector; you are just telling to show the "li" but inside this li you have "ul". 
Therefor, this selector should work:

```
  $(this).find("ul > li").delay(500).slideDown("medium");
```

The whole code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("li").slideUp();
  });

 var hovering=0;
 var element;
 $("ul,li").mouseenter(function (e) {
setTimeout(function(){clearHover();},1000);
if(hovering==0)
{
     hovering=1;
    $("#testdiv").css({"background-color":"red"});
     $(this).find("> li").delay(500).slideDown("medium");
     $(this).find("ul > li").delay(500).slideDown("medium");


     $(".nav").not(this).find("li").delay(500).slideUp();
     $(".nav").not(this).find("li ul").delay(500).slideUp();
   }
 });


function clearHover(){

hovering=0;
    $("#testdiv").css({"background-color":"green"});
};
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcGZJ/74/)

Comment: Have you tried to use your JSFiddle. There are more issues that need to be fixed :)

Comment: hey i am trying another version using show hide, pls look at my second code block!! and the second fiddle. if thats fixed then it will be awesome